# how to use latex to make two signature lines at the same line as in the screenshot

Tags: formatting

[image: Screenshot]
I have no idea how to achieve in Latex. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way with the `tabularx`

[image]

```latex
\\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%%% Temporary
\usepackage{kantlipsum}     % For dummy text
%%% END of temporary

\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]   % Dummy text

\begingroup
    \vspace*{1\baselineskip}%
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.2pt}%
    \renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.5}%
    \sffamily
    \noindent%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
            >{\hspace{12pt}}X 
            c
            @{\hspace{3em}}
            >{\hspace{12pt}}X 
        }
        &&\\[\normalbaselineskip]
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
        Ort, Datum && Unterschrift
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace*{1\baselineskip}
    \par
\endgroup

\kant[1][2]   % Dummy text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I dont anything about this code, but it works, thanks